# Using RowEditing event to update CheckBoxList in Gridview EditTemplate, based on value in ItemTemplate

Tags: asp.net, gridview, checkboxlist

I have a gridview 'gvAccounts' with a column 'Entitlements' (amongst others). Each Entitlements cell contains another gridview 'gvEntitlements', with a list of entitlements for each account (each row in gvAccounts is an account).

In the EditTemplate for the Entitlements cell, I have a CheckBoxList 'cblEntitlements', which is filled with all of the available entitlements.

When I click Edit, I want the cblEntitlements to only have the those entitlements checked which appear in gvEntitlements. I tried a bunch of things in the RowEditing event and nothing worked (lots of null reference errors when using .FindControl on the row), so I thought I would just ask what the best way to do this is, rather than paste my failed attempts.

Thanks!

Markup:

```
<asp:GridView
    ID="gvAccounts"
    runat="server"
    DataSourceID="AccountsObjectDataSource"
    AllowSorting="True"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    DataKeyNames="CorpID,AppKey"
    Width="100%"
    OnRowDataBound="gvAccounts_RowDataBound"
    OnRowEditing="gvAccounts_RowEditing"
    EnableModelValidation="True" >

    <Columns>

        <asp:TemplateField
            HeaderText="Entitlements"
            SortExpression="Entitlements">

            <ItemTemplate>

                    <asp:GridView
                        ID="gvEntitlements"
                        DataKeyNames="EntitlementID"
                        runat="server"
                        ShowHeader="False" 
                        BorderStyle="None" 
                        EmptyDataText="common" 
                        GridLines="None"
                        AutoGenerateColumns="False">

                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField
                                DataField="EntitlementID" 
                                Visible="false" />

                            <asp:BoundField
                                DataField="Entitlement"/>
                        </Columns>

                    </asp:GridView>

            </ItemTemplate>

            <EditItemTemplate>                         

                <asp:CheckBoxList
                    ID="cblEntitlements"
                    runat="server" 
                    DataSourceID="cblObjectDataSource" 
                    DataTextField="Entitlement" 
                    DataValueField="EntitlementID"
                    RepeatColumns="2" 
                    RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                </asp:CheckBoxList>

                <asp:ObjectDataSource
                    ID="cblObjectDataSource"
                    runat="server"
                    SelectMethod="GetAppEntitlements"
                    TypeName="CMRPWebApp.Business.CMRPControllerApps">

                    <SelectParameters>
                        <asp:ControlParameter
                            ControlID="DropDownList1"
                            Name="AppKey"
                            PropertyName="SelectedValue"
                            Type="Int32"/>
                    </SelectParameters>

                </asp:ObjectDataSource>

            </EditItemTemplate>

        </asp:TemplateField>

    </Columns>

</asp:GridView>



<asp:ObjectDataSource
    ID="AccountsObjectDataSource"
    runat="server"
    SelectMethod="GetUsersForApp"
    TypeName="CMRPWebApp.Business.CMRPControllerApps"

    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter  
            ControlID="DropDownList1"
            Name="AppKey"
            PropertyName="SelectedValue"
            Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>

</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

code-behind:

```
protected void gvAccounts_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //for each row, run a query for that appkey + corp ID to retrieve the entitlements for that account.
        System.Collections.Specialized.IOrderedDictionary datakeyNames = gvAccountsApp.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Values;
        string corpID = datakeyNames["CorpID"].ToString();
        int appKey = Convert.ToInt32(datakeyNames["AppKey"]);

        if ((e.Row.FindControl("gvEntitlements") as GridView) != null)
        {
            GridView gv = e.Row.FindControl("gvEntitlements") as GridView;
            gv.DataSource = CMRPControllerApps.GetAccountEntitlements(corpID, appKey);
            gv.DataBind();
        }
    }
}

protected void gvAccounts_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    // ?
}
```

Comment: I think we need more information to help. As it stands right now, the question is too general in nature. Can you post your markup for both GridViews? Also, please provide the DataBinding code for both GridViews.

Comment: Okay - code added. I tried to trim the fat and leave only the relevant code, so hopefully nothing is missing.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding of your question, you want the edit template to show *all* entitlements, with only the entitlements that belong to the specific account being checked.

A couple of things that I noticed:

1. In your code behind, it looks like you are binding something named `GridView1` to the list of entitlements for a specific account. I don't see anything named that in your code.
2. Are you binding to the gridview twice? In your markup I see that you are setting the datasource to `cblEntitlements`. Is this the specific problem you are facing?

I apologize if I am missing the point here, just a little confused.

Comment: Sorry, GridView1 was a typo -- I changed the gridview names here to make it easier to understand, but I missed those 2. It works like this: (1) user selects an application from dropdown, which then binds gvAccounts using AccountsObjectDataSource, then (2): in the RowDataBound event for each row in gvAccounts, each gvEntitlements is bound for that specific account.

Comment: And to your first paragraph; yes, that is exactly how I want it to work. I think the issue I'm having is how to access controls from both the ItemTemplate and EditTempalte in the gvAccounts_RowEditing Event. It would seem that it's only letting me access the ItemTemplate, and thus I am getting a null object error when trying to access the CheckBoxList from the EditTemplate.

Comment: I guess a more concise way to phrase my question is this:   "How do I pass a value retrieved in the RowEditing event to the EditTemplate?"